# I just made android app, how to run it on my phone

Tags: android

Hi I am using Android Studios and just made an application, how do I put it on my phone and run it?

Comment: Did you make any attempt to google this first?  http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run -> Edit Configurations
Select your module and choose the USB radio selection.
Check Deploy Application checkbox.

Attach your device and make sure it has USB debugging enabled under Developer options.

Then just Run and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

or you can find the apk file under ./bin folder,then put this in you phone and install it.